# Proper Use of $.each object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have the following code:

```
$.each($('#someElement audio'), function(i, obj){
    if(obj.play()){
      //do something
    }
});
```

Throwing the following error:
`Object doesn't support property or method 'play'`

Can someone explain why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Can you add some context here? Where/how did you define `play()` and `paused()`? What is `#some element` and why are you trying to `each()` it?

Comment: the object contained in `obj` should  be the same as `$('#some element')[0]`, or, `document.getElementById('someelement')`. so.... this question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: *"use certain generic properties"* ... have absolutely no idea what that means. Suggest reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: when I reference it this way I get an error saying `Object doesn't support property or method 'play'`. I was told the object used in the each loop is a stripped down object that can only reference specific properties/methods. In this case `#some element` is an audio tag.

Comment: Trying to learn `js` and `jquery` so EXCUSE ME! Refactored the question so hopefully you can understand.

Answer (score 0):

The `play()` and `pause()` methods are not available when accessing the jQuery element (i.e. `$('#audioel')`), but only on the actual DOM element (accessible via `$('#audioel')[0]` in jQuery).

If you want to play all audio elements on a given page, you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.audio').each(function() {
    $(this)[0].play();
  });
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/smha4nqz/2/